# How would I mount WiFi antennas inside this small PC?

Tags: antenna, wireless-networking, interference

I am making a small PC and internal antennas would be preferable.
I see devices like Intel NUC and Gigabyte BRIX miniature PCs which have effective internal antennas.

Basically, what type of antenna should I use and how would I mount it? I am hoping to get >50Mbps real speed to my basic UFB Router (802.11n 300Mbps). I have a 100Mbps fibre connection for internet.

The antennas will be near a whole PC worth of electronics/metal.

I'll be connecting the antennas to either a miniPCI-E Realtek RTL8191SE or a USB RTL8192CU.

Alone and mounted high, the USB adapter gets ~60Mbps.

Here is the antennas I am currently trying to use since they are small and easy to mount. They are the exact antennas that are inside my router (I harvested them from a spare). I only get ~15Mbps when they are mounted as pictured. Simply rotating them can reduce it to 3Mbps.

-

[image: Close-up of WiFi antenna]

[image: PC Case with WiFi antennas. What is the optimal positioning?]

[image: USB RTL8192CU Which has the best results so far but is most effective up high]

[image: Other antennas I could take apart and mount inside?]

Comment: Speculation is not as good as trying it out for real.

Comment: The only simple clue is to keep them as far from big metal bits as possible.  RF design is a bit of a dark art and even simulation tools work best in free space environment unless you have lots of time and money for software.  Final design is iterated in anechoic chamber to actually tweak placement and trim elements etc.

Comment: @KalleMP This is antenna from a Mac Mini: https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/olFvlVCjs3AM36ut.standard

I am guessing the black thing is the antenna and the grill is connected to the case so it is probably grounded. Would having my antenna above a plane like this isolate it from other parts? I am unsure how this Mac Mini one works.

Comment: I was going to suggest that electronics.stackexchange.com might be a better place to find the expertise but I see the question was migrated from there.  Antenna theory is outside the scope of this site, so relevant knowledge will be hit or miss.